# I am not getting how to "RETURN" in service layer with generic pattern

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, service

Here is my sample code :

```
public SupportArticle Dropdown()
    {
      IRepository<Supportwife> iRepo = new GenericRepository<Supportwife>(_factory.ContextFactory);
      var tp = iRepo.Get().Select(st => new SelectListItem()
      {
        Text = st.Name,
        Value = st.TypeID.ToString(),
      });
      return tp;// here ,i am getting error while returning tp
    }
```

The error is:

> can not convert system.collection.generic to cms.model.supportwife.

What I want is: to return the function so that I can use the drop-down function on my controller.
Note: this is service layer code

Comment: `.Get().Select()` returns a collection. Dropdown is expecting to return a *single item*. The error simply states that a  `Collection<X>` (collection of things) cannot be converted to an `X` (single thing) implicitly.

Comment: Also: "Generic Repositories" can bite me :}

Comment: How about returning first item `.FirstOrDefault()` that exception is clear cannot cast collection to one item.

Comment: @user2864740..can you provide me sample of doing it in correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq's `Select()` method always returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.
You can get only a single item or null back by using the `FirstOrDefault()` method.

But, even if you do that - your method is declared as returning `SupportArticle`, while your `Select` is creating an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - after using the `FirstOrDefault()` method you are left with an reference of type `SelectListItem` - Unless that type can be implicitly converted to `SupportArticle`, you will still get a cast exception.

You need to either change the return type of the method or change the type you are selecting from `iRepo`.

Something like this should get you where you want to go:

```
public SelectListItem Dropdown()
{
  var iRepo = new GenericRepository<Supportwife>(_factory.ContextFactory);
  return iRepo.Get().Select(st => new SelectListItem()
  {
    Text = st.Name,
    Value = st.TypeID.ToString(),
  }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you want your method to return a `List<SelectListItem>`, you only need to change the method's return type and the `FirstOrDefault()` to `ToList()`:
(note that I'm no longer using the `iRepo` variable - it's just to show that it's possible to do it like this also)

```
public List<SelectListItem> Dropdown()
{
  return new GenericRepository<Supportwife>(_factory.ContextFactory)
                 .Get()
                 .Select(st => new SelectListItem()
  {
    Text = st.Name,
    Value = st.TypeID.ToString(),
  }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: what if i send List<SelectListItem>..it is saying..List<T> doesnt contain Text and value..can u help

Comment: Again, glad to help :-)

Comment: Ihhave one more problem. little problem can you please suggestthe solution ??

Comment: Perhaps I can, but please be aware that Stackoverflow is not a forum, it's a Q & A website. Different problems deserves different questions. A single question should cover only a single problem. If you have a new problem you should post it in a new question.

Comment: I have posted it as per you suggest me. Kindly visit and answer it Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073950/how-to-convert-this-code-to-service-pattern