# How to convert this code to service pattern?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, service

Here is my code :

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCategor(int catId)
    {
      using (uuEntities ems = new uuEntities())
      {
        return Json(ems.SupportSubCats.Where(x => x.CatID == catId).Select(
        x => new
        {
          SubId = x.SubCatID,
          SUbName = x.SubCatName
        }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
    }
```

What I have tried :

In controller :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCategor(int catId)
    {
        return Json(_service.List(int catId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
    }
```

In Service :

```
    public void List(int catId)
    {
      return new GenericRepository<SupportSubCategory>(_factory.ContextFactory)
        .Get(filter: (x => x.CatID == catId))
        .Select(x => new
        {
          SubId = x.SubCatID,
          SUbName = x.SubCatName
        }).ToList();
    }
```

I think my return type is incorrect please suggest me the solution. Near public void, i am getting an error that void can not return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `void` methods does not return any value to it's caller.
You can use an empty `return` in a `void` method only to exit the method - but you can't return any value.

This code is perfectly valid and widely used as a common practice:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    if(<someCondition>)
    {
        return;
    }
    // The rest of the code will only be executed if <someCondition> evalualtes to false
}
```

Usually, you use this pattern when you are passing parameters into the method and need to validate them before actually performing the rest of the method.

This code, however, is not valid and **will not compile**:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    if(<someCondition>)
    {
        return false; // Here is your compiler error...
    }
    // The rest of the code will only be executed if <someCondition> evalualtes to false
}
```

Following our conversation in the comments, you should probably create a class to hold the results of the `Select` instead of using an anonymous type, and return a list of that class from your method:

```
// Note: I've renamed your method to something a little bit more meaningful
public List<SubDetails> ListSubDetails(int catId) 
{
  return new GenericRepository<SupportSubCategory>(_factory.ContextFactory)
    .Get(filter: (x => x.CatID == catId))
    .Select(x => new SubDetails()
    {
      SubId = x.SubCatID,
      SUbName = x.SubCatName
    }).ToList();
}
```

...

```
public class SubDetails
{
    public Int SubId {get; set;} // I'm guessing int here...
    public string SUbName {get; set;} // I'm guessing string here...
 }
```

Comment: using simple return with null, it is giving error in controller : "cannot convert void to object  " near catId

Comment: Yes, because `null` is a reference that is simply not set to any object. If you are using `return` in a `void` method, it can only be used like this: `return;`. Everything else would create a compiler error.

Comment: then what should i use in place of void ?

Comment: My first code in controller is working.. but now, i am using service so i want to wite that logic in service and call it to controller... kindly suggest me the wayto solve it

Comment: You should either not return anything from the method, or create a type with `SubId` and `SUbName` and select it instead of your anonymous type, and then return a list of that type.

Comment: public SupportSubCategory List(int catId)
    {
     var it = new GenericRepository<SupportSubCategory>(_factory.ContextFactory)
          .Get(filter: (x => x.CatID == catId))
          .Select(x => new
          {
            SubId = x.SubCatID,
            SUbName = x.SubCatName
          }).ToList();
      return it;
      }

Comment: Error : return type list<Subdetail> is less accessible than service list

Comment: it should be a public class, sorry for forgetting to include that. fixed.

Comment: Wow, Works like a charm :) Thanks a lot Zohar:)

Comment: Hey Zohar, Can i talk further if i will get any error in my project? Only if you are ok with that :)

Comment: I would rather not to. It's better for you and for SO if you posted your questions here instead of asking a specific person (which may or may not know the answer).

Comment: Yea I got you.  Anyways Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076470/how-to-do-proper-join-using-lambda-notation-when-you-have-four-tables.... See this please